# How can I tell which commands are deprecated?

Tags: command-line, versions

In Ubuntu, I was wondering if there was any way that I could view an updated source on what commands were deprecated/no longer supported in updated releases (non [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)). I wanted to know because I think it would be useful information to know when performing specific tasks if the command you are using is deprecated.

This will give you more of an idea of how to do the task in a better/more efficient way. Obviously, this list would be long, so an organizer would be necessary to categorize by date-deprecated, type of command, alphabetical order, Ubuntu version, etc. Not all of these are necessary but are the baseline for the organizing that would be optimal.

**Overall, is there a way that I can see a broad list of what commands are deprecated in Ubuntu on supported releases?**

Comment: If a command is deprecated, you'll be informed through regular channel. Most of that happens by inserting a message to the end user of the deprecated command. But these is no such listing of deprecated commands

Comment: @Anwar yeah, I was hoping that there was. But hopefully this question will help out some other people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO, there is no such listing for all deprecated commands.

It depends on each package and its developer and whether they are printing deprecation message for the command or not. Every package has a community channel and release notes by which they share what the changes are in new releases. This includes the functionalities that are deprecated.